# Exoplayer FFMPEG issue. Video froze on the first frame after adding Exoplayer FFMPEG extension

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ffmpeg, exoplayer2.x

I am working on adding Exoplayer and it works fine. But some of the videos were playing without audio, it plays fine in VLC medial player. So I was suggested to add Exoplayer FFMPEG. I added Exoplayer FFMPEG extension and I modified the code as below,

```
val videoTrackSelectionFactory: TrackSelection.Factory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER)
val trackSelector: TrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)

val renderersFactory: RenderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(mContext, null, EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER)
mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, renderersFactory, trackSelector)
mediaSource = mMediaSourceUri?.let { createLeafMediaSource(it) }!!
mPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
```

After I modified the video stuck with the first frame and it keeps on loading. I checked the log and I didn't see any error.

[image: Code Sample]

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!